# Azure active directory returns 203 for API call

Tags: c#, wpf, bearer-token, azureportal

Trying to use an Azure Active Directory to make a user authenticated API call and get releases for my project from a WPF desktop application. Created the Active Directory and added a permission for `https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/user_impersonation` in order to make API calls.

However, the code sample provided by the Azure Portal only works with the default permission `https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read`, using endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` and scope `user.read`. Switching to the endpoint to get releases for my project and changing the scope to `https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/user_impersonation` results in a 203 "Non-Authoritative Information" response.

Using a hardcoded base-64 encoded PAT works for this request, but the bearer token returned from the active directory login only works for the `https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read` query authorized using `request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);`.

```
Microsoft.Identity.Client.AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
var app = App.PublicClientApp;
string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/user_impersonation" };
var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
var firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();

try
{
    authResult = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, firstAccount)
                .ExecuteAsync();
}
catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}");
    try
    {
        authResult = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                              .WithAccount(accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                              .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
                              .ExecuteAsync();
    }
    catch (MsalException msalex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error Acquiring Token:{System.Environment.NewLine}{msalex}");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error Acquiring Token Silently:{System.Environment.NewLine}{ex}");
    return;
}
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
    System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response;
    try
    {
        var request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get,
                    @"https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{...}/_apis/release/releases?propertyFilters=7425&searchText=Dashboard&api-version=5.1");

        request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        using (response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            ...
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide your code?

Comment: The code that results in the 203 response has been added

Comment: Please refer to the sample: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/tree/master/ManagedClientConsoleAppSample